# Programatically edit image with aviary/feather?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, aviary, adobecreativesdk

Is there any way to execute command with Aviary/Feather? E.g. let's say I want to edit an image but first I want to crop it via JavaScript (instead of relying on the user to crop it to my specific ratio). I know I can set the allowed crop ratios but I'd like a way to do this automatically and ensure the crop is applied by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatic edits are not currently possible with the Image Editor. The use paradigm is:

1. Configure the Image Editor
2. Launch the Image Editor and pass in an image
3. Receive the resulting edited image